# Cast Collection<DependantInterface> to Collection<RootInterface> fail

Tags: java

I have the

`Interface  SpecialData extends RootData { ..}`

I cannot compile this operation :

```
Collection<SpecialData> collSpecData = ...;
Collection<RootData> collRootData = ...;
collRootData.add((Collection<RootData>) collSpecData );
```

**Edited**

```
Collection<SpecialData> collSpecData = ...;
ArrayList<Collection<RootData>> collRootData = ...; // Correction here : adding ArrayList
collRootData.add((Collection<RootData>) collSpecData );
```

So, have I to iterate `SpecialData` and *cast* each field? Or is more elegant solution available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to add all the elements from one collection to another, you can use [`Collection#addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#addAll%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
Collection<SpecialData> collSpecData = ...;
Collection<RootData> collRootData = ...;
collRootData.addAll(collSpecData);
```

---

By your edit, you can do a *quick fix* by redefining `collRootData` as `ArrayList<Collection<? extends RootData>>`. This is a basic example based on your current code:

```
Collection<SpecialData> collSpecData = new ArrayList<SpecialData>();
ArrayList<Collection<? extends RootData>> collRootData = new ArrayList<Collection<? extends RootData>>();
collRootData.add(collSpecData);
```

Comment: You are right, I made a mistake in my question : it is `ArrayList<Collection<RootData>>`

Comment: @cl-r then edit your question and add the code that shows your specific problem, but do not remove the previous content otherwise this and the other answers would be invalid. I'll update my answer based on your edit.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Yes, you have to iterate and cast each member. The reason for this is that `Collection<RootData>` is not a superclass of `Collection<SpecialData>`.</s>

Actually I recommend this:

```
Collection<SpecialData> collSpecData = //...
Collection<RootData> collRootData = //empty constructor
collRootData.addAll(collSpecData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If a `Collection<Bicycle>` was a `Collection<Vehicle>`, you could do

```
Collection<Bicycle> bicycles = ...;
Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = bicycles;
vehicles.add(new Car());
```

which would make the generic collections type-unsafe.

Your method should prabably take a `Collection<? extends RootData>` as argument, because you really don't want this method to add something other than a `SpecialData` to the collection. If that's what you want, then you need a copy of the collection, to make sure the original collection keeps being a `Collection<SpecialData>`, and doesn't contain anything else.

Comment: I cannot copy bicycles to vehicules, because I have many bicycles Collection to add in vehicules.

Comment: And? Why does the fact that there are many collections prevent you from copying them? Why don't you simply change the type to `ArrayList<Collection<? extends RootData>>`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've miswrited my answer. Luiggui Mendoza gave me the solution I expected.